# PowerDNS master server doesn't notify

Tags: nameserver, powerdns, slave

I have a PowerDNS based master nameserver with 3 slaves. Zone transfer works through AXFR (automatically once every hour it gets checked by the slaves). When I change a record through our panel the notified_serial gets updated correctly as well as the serial in the SOA record.

The nameserver uses a MySQL backend. The slaves don't get notified when changes occur. Nothing is logged when it was supposed to send a Notify. When I force a notify (like: pdns_control notify example.com) the slaves get  notified properly.

The config is as follows:

```
master=yes
setuid=pdns
setgid=pdns
local-address=xx.xxx.xx.xxx
allow-axfr-ips=xx.xxx.xx.xxx

use-logfile=yes
log-dns-details=yes
log-failed-updates=yes
logging-facility=0
loglevel=4

launch=gmysql
gmysql-host=localhost
gmysql-user=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
gmysql-password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
gmysql-dbname=powerdns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't update `notified_serial` in your panel; powerdns is supposed to update this **after** it sent the NOTIFY. See `update-serial-query` in [Master/slave queries](http://doc.powerdns.com/html/generic-mypgsql-backends.html#master-slave-queries).

powerdns will send a NOTIFY if it sees `notified_serial != SOA.serial`.

Comment: I feel like a idiot.. before we used MySQL replication so I never had any problems with it. It works now! Thanks!

Comment: I have having same issue and still not fix :(

Comment: found issue, issue was `NS` record in master was missing